# multi level Accordion issue ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, accordion

i am new to ionic and trying to build multi level menu in my application using Accordion . its working fine from subcategories when i try to add products it got closed every time on click on subcategory.

here is my html code :-

```html
<ion-content class="menu_cont"> <ion-list>
<div ng-repeat="list in wholecatagoryList">
 <ion-item class="item-stable" ng-click="toggleGroup(list)"
  ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(list)}"> <i class="icon"
  ng-class="isGroupShown(list) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i> &nbsp;
 {{list.title}} </ion-item>
 <ion-item class="item-accordion"
  ng-repeat="subcatagorylist in list.children"
  ng-show="isGroupShown(list)" ng-click="toggleGroup(subcatagorylist)"
  ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(subcatagorylist)}"> <i
  class="icon"
  ng-class="isGroupShown(subcatagorylist) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
 &nbsp; {{subcatagorylist.title}}
 <ion-item class="item-accordion"
  ng-repeat="Productlist in subcatagorylist.children"
  ng-show="isGroupShown(subcatagorylist)">
 {{Productlist.title}} </ion-item> 
 </ion-item>

</div>
</ion-list> </ion-content>
```

here is my json response :-

```
[
{
    "id": "165",
    "title": "Women's Fashion",
    "url": "womens-fashion",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "176",
            "title": "Women's Aparel",
            "url": "women-s-aparel",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "221",
                    "title": "Formal",
                    "url": "formal"
                },
                {
                    "id": "222",
                    "title": "Casual",
                    "url": "casual"
                },
                {
                    "id": "223",
                    "title": "Traditional",
                    "url": "traditional"
                },
                {
                    "id": "224",
                    "title": "Nightwears",
                    "url": "nightwears"
                },
                {
                    "id": "225",
                    "title": "Winter wears",
                    "url": "winter-wears"
                },
                {
                    "id": "240",
                    "title": "Party Wear",
                    "url": "party-wear"
                }
            ]
        }
```

]

here is my toggelGroup code :-

```js
$scope.wholecatagoryList = [];
if (response.data.length > 0) {
  $scope.wholecatagoryList = response.data;
}

$scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
  if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
    $scope.shownGroup = null;
  } else {
    $scope.shownGroup = group;
  }
};
$scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
  return $scope.shownGroup === group;
};
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you want like this - http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uJkCz

Comment: Hey Divyesh , thanks for your reply and yes i am using the same demo in my project , but i am not able to put more childes with accordion in it ..

Comment: try like this- http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVWQqR this is just startup....you can follow same thing for sub children